# Bootstrap 5.3.0 - Dropdown in navbar out of collapsed area makes dropdown's menu inside the navbar instead of outside

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown, bootstrap-5

When the navbar is collapsed, the dropdown outside of the collapsed area shows dropdown's menu in the navbar's body. Does any know how to solve this? I've studied the attributes like data-bs-reference but there's not much info.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-md">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="news-logo.png" width="100px"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler order-first" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#mynavbar"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse order-last order-md-1" id="mynavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">items...</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <ul class="navbar-nav order-md-2 ">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown ms-md-auto">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#">User</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Account</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the source I noticed that changing menu's position to absolute would do the trick.

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu position-absolute">
```